# move an element from a div to another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's assume that I have this structure

```
 <div class="firstDiv">
  <div class="insideDiv"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="secondDiv"></div>
 <div class="thirdDiv"></div>
```

How can I move the `.insideDiv` from the `.firstDiv` to the `.thirdDiv` but going through the `.secondDiv` ?

I need just a hint or an idea. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by going through?

Comment: Can you provide any code that you have written to try this?

Comment: I mean not passing by .secondDiv . When the "event" it's triggered the .insideDiv should move inside the .secondDiv and if the event it's triggered again the .insideDiv moves to .thirdDiv

Comment: `.addEventListener()` + `.querySelector()` + (`.appendChild()` or `.insertAdjacentElement()`)

Comment: Take a look at this. Really easy to do https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: @Paulie_D I have done some research. I want to do a pacman using react but I have no clue how to make the pacman which is a div to cross the other divs that I have. I need an idea or a hint not to write my code. I believe I wrote an understandable example

Comment: @DanielBisceanu to place/move an element on top of another element, you can set the position of the movable element to absolute so it is taken out of the normal document flow. It seems to that you are attempting to do something difficult without grasping the basics first

Comment: In event listener (click or smth) you should do smth like 
`document.querySelector(".secondDiv")
 .appendChild(document.querySelector(".insideDiv"))`
and then 
`document.querySelector(".thirdDiv")
 .appendChild(document.querySelector(".insideDiv"))`

Comment: I agree with @Huangism. You're going about this the wrong way and making this a lot harder than it should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vanilla JS, it works like this:

```js
var moveIt = function() {
  var outerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('insideDiv')[0].parentElement;
  var innerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('insideDiv')[0];

  if (outerDiv.nextElementSibling != null) {
    outerDiv.nextElementSibling.appendChild(outerDiv.removeChild(innerDiv));
  }
}
```

```css
.firstDiv {
  background-color: yellow
}

.secondDiv {
  background-color: lightblue
}

.thirdDiv {
  background-color: lightpink
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstDiv">first
    <div class="insideDiv">inside div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondDiv">second</div>
  <div class="thirdDiv">third</div>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="moveIt()">Move it!</button>
```

OPTIONAL: wrap-around in else statement below, this needs a scope to operate in. (set by div-element of class 'container'), to be added to above if statement.

```
else { outerDiv.parentElement.firstElementChild.appendChild(outerDiv.removeChild(innerDiv));
  }
```

You can see a working example here: [codepen: move child-element to nextSibling](https://codepen.io/lumbela/full/qxKwjr)

Comment: FWIW I'd use `document.querySelector()` and not use inline event handlers.

Comment: @hungerstar: Thanks for your comment, I was wondering what would be your reason(s) to go for .querySelector( ... ) (... instead of .getElementsByClassName( ... )[0] I guess?)

Comment: Because it's more flexible. You can use whatever CSS selector you'd like with `querySelecotr()` and `querySelectorAll()`. I'd also not query the DOM twice like you did with `getElementsByClassName()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using jquery:

```
   <div class="firstDiv">
      <div class="insideDiv">InsideBaseball</div>
   </div>
   <div class="secondDiv">SecondBase</div>
   <div class="thirdDiv">ThirdBase</div>
     <button id="SwapButton"> Swap! </button>  


<script>

document.getElementById("SwapButton").onclick = function () { 
    var content = $('.insideDiv').html();
    var content2 = $('.thirdDiv').html();
    $('.thirdDiv').replaceWith(content);
    $('.insideDiv').replaceWith(content2);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: It's interesting that you suggested jQuery but choose `getElementById().onclick`. Why not go full jQuery an go `$( '#SwapButton' ).on( 'click', function () {} )`?

Comment: Because I'm a total noob. Much cleaner answer, thanks.